# How to mock a function with mockito

Tags: kotlin, mockito

```
  val listener = mock<() -> Unit>()
```

How do I create a mock like this? The compiler always complains about it. I want to check if a listener gets invoked later on. I tried latest mockito 3.1 and also 2.28.2 (Android Versions).

Answer (score 0):

I was not using mockito-kotlin as dependency.

Add this to my build.gradle makes it work as expected:

```
androidTestImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0",
```